# how to find cause of io spike

Tags: mysql, troubleshooting, io

Everyday at **around** the same time, the IO usage on the server where our mysql slave goes up to 100%.

I have setup a script that takes IO information every five minutes so I can find out why this happens.

So far I can see that a mysql process is causing this spike, but I can't find out what mysql is actually doing to cause this.

Using `pidstat` I get:

```
Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 (-db03)        09/03/2014      _x86_64_        (24 CPU)
03:30:05 AM       PID   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s  Command
03:30:20 AM       418      0.00      5.06      0.00  jbd2/sda1-8
03:30:20 AM     31124    878.88  12179.08      0.00  mysqld

03:30:20 AM       PID   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s  Command
03:30:35 AM       418      0.00      1.07      0.00  jbd2/sda1-8
03:30:35 AM     31124   1124.80  12924.00      0.00  mysqld

Average:          PID   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s  Command
Average:          418      0.00      3.07      0.00  jbd2/sda1-8
Average:        31124   1001.80  12551.42      0.00  mysqld
```

Using `pt-mysql-summary` I get:

```
# Processlist ################################################

  Command                        COUNT(*) Working SUM(Time) MAX(Time)
  ------------------------------ -------- ------- --------- ---------
  Connect                               2       2   3500000   3500000
  Query                                 1       1         0         0
  Sleep                                 2       0        15         8

  User                           COUNT(*) Working SUM(Time) MAX(Time)
  ------------------------------ -------- ------- --------- ---------
  monitoring                            2       0         0         0
  root                                  1       1         0         0
  system user                           2       2   3500000   3500000

  Host                           COUNT(*) Working SUM(Time) MAX(Time)
  ------------------------------ -------- ------- --------- ---------
                                        2       2   3500000   3500000
  localhost                             3       1         0         0

  db                             COUNT(*) Working SUM(Time) MAX(Time)
  ------------------------------ -------- ------- --------- ---------
  flats_production                      2       1       600       600
  NULL                                  3       2   3500000   3500000

  State                          COUNT(*) Working SUM(Time) MAX(Time)
  ------------------------------ -------- ------- --------- ---------
                                        2       0         0         0
  init                                  1       1         0         0
  updating                              1       1       600       600
  Waiting for master to send eve        1       1   3500000   3500000
```

But `show full processlist` does not show anything abnormal.

Any idea on how I can debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Take pt-ioprofile and check, what mysql is reading and writing. http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-ioprofile.html